# How can I tell how many nodes are in my YARN cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I want to find out how many nodes are in a yarn cluster that I'm working on.
I don't have any admin Ambari privileges and I can see the yarn UI page and I can see the nodes page.
I can see there are 4 nodes.

However, can someone tell me does that mean there are 4 nodes running yarn Node Manager, or is that 4 nodes that have yarn containers already spun up?
Don't direct me to the yarn documentation!
I've already been looking through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just ask the people who do have access to Ambari (maybe even ask if they let you get a read only account).

The YARN UI tells you both, though. It tells you how many nodes are available, the sum of all available node memory, and the number of running, pending, and allocated containers.

If no containers are up, the nodes are still listed